# Ambiguous column name error in Inner Join

Tags: sql, join

I am trying to extract information from 4 tables using inner join

For example :

TableC has the following columns:

```
F_name, L_Name, A_ID
```

TableN has the following:

```
Sub, Date, A_ID, N_ID, O_ID
```

TableM has the following columns:

```
Desc, Abbr, N_ID
```

TableO has the following:

```
F_name, L_Name, O_ID,
```

So my query which i am trying is

```
Select C.F_Name, C.L_Name, N.Sub, N.Date, M.Desc, M.Abbr, O.F_Name, O.L_Name
From TableN N
Inner Join TableC C
On N.A_ID = C.A_ID
Inner Join TableM M
On N.N_ID=M.N_ID
Inner Join TableO O
On O.O_ID=N.O_ID
```

I have described the scenario above, when I am running the query I am getting the following error:

Ambiguous column name 'F_Name'

Comment: Use the `AS` keyword to rename one of the columns which has the name `F_Name` like `C.F_Name AS CFName`

Comment: Though you've specified which table they each come from, you've still selected 2 `F_Name` columns for the result set -- `C.F_Name` and `O.F_Name`. Give one or both of them a distinct alias -- `O.F_Name AS O_F_Name`. You'll also have this issue with `L_Name`.

Comment: Are you retrieving the result columns by name? E.g. Oracle would not issue this warning otherwise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ambiguous column name error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/318066/3404097)

Answer (score 4):

Use aliases. Try this.

```
Select C.F_Name as CFNAME, C.L_Name as CLNAME, N.Sub, N.Date
    , M.Desc, M.Abbr, O.F_Name as OFNAME, O.L_Name as OLNAME
From TableN N
Inner Join TableC C On N.A_ID = C.A_ID
Inner Join TableM M On N.N_ID=M.N_ID
Inner Join TableO O On O.O_ID=N.O_ID
```

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar problem when joining two tables. In my case, this is what I used:

```
public function PdfVista(){

 $this->db->select ('Clientes.idCliente, Cotizaciones.nomCotizacion, Cotizaciones.compCliente, Cotizaciones.nomProyecto,Cotizaciones.agente, Cotizaciones.fVenCotizacion, Cotizaciones.fModCotizacion, Clientes.razSocCliente, Clientes.telFijoCliente');

 $this->db->from('Cotizaciones');

 $this->db->join('Clientes', 'Clientes.idCliente=Cotizaciones.idCliente');

 $this->db->where('idCliente',10000);

 $respuesta = $this->db->get();

 return $respuesta->result();
}
```

but at the time of put the where, the idClient columns were repeated, both for the Clientes and Cotizaciones tables, I had to put:

`$this->db->where('Clientes.idCliente',10000);`

to detect the table I wanted to check

Comment: This is English SO.