# Getting column name ambigous

Tags: mysql, sql

I have query in which i am getting column 'month' ambigious . I am trying with following query. Please check nd help me.

```
SELECT SC.name as sc,
       B.name as brand,
       COUNT(T.id) as tc,
       SUM(IF(is_category_present = 1, 1, 0)) as BASE
FROM outlet_categories OC 
     INNER JOIN transactions T ON OC.outlet_id = T.outlet_id 
     inner join outlets O on O.id = T.outlet_id 
     inner join brands B on T.brand_id = B.id 
     inner join sale_channels SC on SC.id =  O.sale_channel_id
WHERE T.month = month
```

Comment: need to define the table aliase in where cluase WHERE T.month = month

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ambiguous column name error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318066/ambiguous-column-name-error)

Comment: Since that column name exists in at least two tables, you have to qualify it each time it's referenced, just like `T.month`.

Comment: Did you search for your problem? This question has been asked many many many times before.

Comment: You need to use the table alias for your final month in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qualify all your column names.  It is not clear what the right names are, but these need table aliases:

```
SELECT SC.name as sc, B.name as brand,
       COUNT(T.id) as tc,
-------^ Looks like an aggregation query, but there is no `GROUP BY`.
       SUM(IF(is_category_present = 1, 1, 0)) as BASE
--------------^
FROM outlet_categories OC INNER JOIN
     transactions T
     ON OC.outlet_id = T.outlet_id INNER JOIN
     outlets O 
     ON O.id = T.outlet_id INNER JOIN
     brands B 
     ON T.brand_id = B.id INNER JOIN
     sale_channels SC 
     ON SC.id =  O.sale_channel_id
WHERE T.month = month;
----------------^
```

Three notes about MySQL:

- Your `IF()` is not necessary.
- I am guessing that `month` is a variable.  If so, name it something else.
- Presumably, you want a `GROUP BY`.

A better version of the query:

```
SELECT SC.name as sc, B.name as brand, COUNT(T.id) as tc,
       SUM(??.is_category_present) as BASE
FROM outlet_categories OC INNER JOIN
     transactions T
     ON OC.outlet_id = T.outlet_id INNER JOIN
     outlets O 
     ON O.id = T.outlet_id INNER JOIN
     brands B 
     ON T.brand_id = B.id INNER JOIN
     sale_channels SC 
     ON SC.id =  O.sale_channel_id
WHERE T.month = v_month
GROUP BY SC.name, B.name;
```

The variable `month` has been renamed `v_month`, so it is no confused with a column name.  MySQL will interpret `T.month = month` as `T.month = T.month` -- assuming that `month` is only in the `T` table.  And, I'm guessing that `T.month = T.month` is not your intention.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a column named month in more than one table then you have to specify the table it comes from, otherwise the database doesn't know which of the columns named month you refer to.

Comment: yes month field is iin Outlet_category and transactions T. can you please tell me, how you are saying?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SC.name as sc,
       B.name as brand,
       COUNT(T.id) as tc,
       SUM(IF(is_category_present = 1, 1, 0)) as BASE /* <-- from with table this column? add alias*/
FROM outlet_categories OC 
     INNER JOIN transactions T ON OC.outlet_id = T.outlet_id 
     inner join outlets O on O.id = T.outlet_id 
     inner join brands B on T.brand_id = B.id 
     inner join sale_channels SC on SC.id =  O.sale_channel_id
WHERE T.month = month /* <-- from with table this column month? add alias*/
```

This error means than you have, for example, column `test` in several tables and SQL doesn't know where take this column - from table1 or table2, for example.